# How to make FadeInImage Circular?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using `FadeInImage` Widget to show a Network Image in my App. As I want to use the placeholder property of FadeInImage, I can't use `NetworkImage` or `Image.Network` Widget.

Now I want to make `FadeInImage` circular so I tried to use following options.

1. I tried wrapping `FadeInImage` inside `Container` to make it circular but the `DecorationImage` property does not allow `FadeInImage`
2. I tried using `CircleAvatar` but backgroundImage property of `CircleAvatar`  does not allow `FadeInImage`
3. I tried using `cached_network_image` library of flutter but was facing the same issue
4. Last option I tried was using `ClipRRect` to make it circular but still it does not work

Following is my code

```
Container(
      width: 50.0,
      height: 50.0,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        child: FadeInImage(
            placeholder: AssetImage("images/alex.jpg"),
            image: NetworkImage(
                "https://cdn1.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/scale_crop_768_433/2018/02/gettyimages-862145286_copy_-_h_2018.jpg")),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set the width and height property of FadeInImage and it should work.

```
ClipOval(
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      placeholder: AssetImage("images/alex.jpg"),
      imageUrl:"https://cdn1.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/scale_crop_768_433/2018/02/gettyimages-862145286_copy_-_h_2018.jpg",
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: @Nudge just edited my answer. Try it with cachednetworkImage. I do it all the time and it works.

Comment: does not work. Can you share a screenshot if you have achieved the result?

Comment: @Nudge just did. I actually added a fit property to the CachedNetworkImage so that the image will fill the entire area. If it's not working for you, you are not using the exact code I provided you. CachedNetworkImage has to be the direct child of ClipRRect for this to work.

Comment: I copy pasted your code but still not able to achieve this. Here is my code. 
main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {return ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),child: CachedNetworkImage(fit: BoxFit.cover,width: 50,height:50,imageUrl:"https://cdn1.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/scale_crop_768_433/2018/02/gettyimages-862145286_copy_-_h_2018.jpg",placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),),);}}

Comment: @Nudge Your code looks fine to me. At this point, it might be the version your using. Try to upgrade everything you're using; flutter, CachedNetworkImage, etc...

Comment: @ dshukertjr I am using the latest version of flutter and cachednetworkimage

Comment: @Nudge Okay, then try wrapping your ClipRRect with Material app.

Comment: @ dshukertjr I am such an idiot that I forgot the Material app and Scaffold. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Nudge I did not know having those matter. Glad to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This work for me, I have been searching for a lot on the internet.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend CachedNetworkImage, as it's currently incompatible with http 1.0.0

Answer (score 8):

Wrap `FadeInImage` widget with `ClipOval` then wrao `ClipOval` widget with `AspectRatio`:

```dart
AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1/1,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: "Your-placeholder-path",
            image: "Your-Image-Url"),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom widget for this:

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircleCachedNetworkAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  final double size;

  CircleCachedNetworkAvatar({@required this.url, this.size = 50.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: size,
        width: size,
        child: url != null
            ? ClipOval(
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  fadeInDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
                  fadeOutDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
                  imageUrl: url,
                  placeholder: Container(
                      color: Colors.greenAccent, child: Icon(Icons.person)),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              )
            : CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: Icon(Icons.person)));
  }
}
```

What do you think about this code?

Comment: I tried your solution but the image occupies the whole screen. I am not sure why instead of giving a default size of 50 in the constructor and the image looks oval instead of circle. The second problem is that just for a few milliseconds the screen show an error before displaying the image

Comment: Just for testing, can you try to wrap `CircleCachedNetworkAvatar` in a `Center` widget?

Comment: The Centre Widget works but I tried to pass a wrong url so instead of showing the placeholder Icon, I am getting an error from CachedNetworkImageProvider saying could not download or retrieve the file

Comment: Ok, I understand. If you pass a correct url the effect is what are you looking for?

Comment: ClipOval was the key for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            placeholder: AssetImage("images/alex.jpg"),
            imageUrl: "<IMAGE URL>"),
      );
```

This worked for me, have a look.